# Allow One setAttribute() to Prevent Another One

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I have an entity which I've created two setAttribute functions for:

```
public function setStartAttribute($value) { }
```

and

```
public function setEndAttribute($value) { }
```

These attributes, **start** and **end**, are both datetimes which I check against some criteria in each of my setter function before allowing. Under certain conditions, I prevent or allow the **start** or **end** attributes to be updated.

I've hit a wall, however, in that if I prevent one of these from being updated, I need to prevent both. In other words, if the user tries to update the entity with a **start** date which is out of bounds, I need to prevent the **start** date from being updated, but I also need to prevent the **end** date from being update.

As these are two separate functions, I'm not sure how to use one to prevent the other in a case like this.

***EDIT:***

Since the answer is extremely obvious (just do it both in one function) without adding this extra info, I'll add that the part that makes this less straightforward is that I'm using Backpack for Laravel. Within the Backpack admin panel is the CRUD that lets me create or update my entity. I'm using the date_range field type to allow setting the ***start*** and ***end*** time/dates on my entity. It's upon saving this that I need to be able to pass both the ***start*** and ***end*** values to a function and validate them, prior to setting them on my entity. I found that creating the two separate functions above setStartAttribute() and setEndAttribute() allowed me to validate those values and choose whether to assign them to the entity, however I need to be able to use one unified function rather than two separate ones. It is this integration with Backpack which makes this problem less straightforward for me.

Comment: Can you describe about criteria as well ? So that optimal solution may be found ?

Comment: You should probably do it in validation before you get to altering the model

Answer (score 1):

If those `start` and `end` attributes are connected somehow (one can't be set if another is invalid), you better make one method to set both of them. Something like this:

```
public function setStartAndEnd($start, $end)
{
    if ($start is valid && $end is valid)
    {
        $this->start = $start;
        $this->end = $end;
    }
}
```

Which you can use as follows:

```
$entity->setStartAndEnd($date, $another_date);
```

Comment: I've added some additional information which more thoroughly describes the problem, as the answer is extremely straightforward and obvious without the extra information about Backpack for Laravel.

Comment: As far as the [date_range field](https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/docs/crud-fields#section-date_range) goes, you need two pass two field names (start_name and end_name), so it matches your use case perfectly with "start" and "end". Once the input reaches the model, it has nothing to do with Backpack anymore, it's just Laravel doing its thing. So Martin's answer here should work perfectly for you. Just call this method inside both your Mutators. The Backpack integration shouldn't be a problem. What happens in the model stays in the model :-)